# Exporting Report to Pdf from Crystal Report it's getting too much time

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, report, delay

I am trying to export pdf from Crystal Report Viewer. But it is taking too much time. We are using .Net 2.0 with Crystal Report 11. So please give me the solution for the delay of exporting.

Comment: How many pages long is the PDF? How much time does it take? Is it rendered fast in the viewer? Do you have subreports in your report?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add this to the crystal report object:

```
pdfFormatOptions.UsePageRange = True
```

It should take 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
        CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
        CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
        CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
        **pdfFormatOptions.UsePageRange = True**

        crystalReport.Refresh()
```