# Crystal Report export take forever

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, webapi

I am struggling with exporting a Crystal Report to a Word document.

I'm creating the report with this code:

```
using (ReportDocument initRep = report.SetUpReportDocument(rep, loadId))
{
    string filePath = @"C:\word2Pdf\";
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "wordReport.doc";

    var fileNameAndPath = filePath + fileName;
    initRep.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, fileNameAndPath);
 }
```

The problem is located here, on this line of code:

```
 initRep.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, fileNameAndPath);
```

This is taking forever, with no any error.

My report has 4 subreports, which are linked to the main report with unique Id (`loadId`).

I have been researching a lot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201024/exporting-report-to-pdf-from-crystal-report-its-getting-too-much-time) or [even here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2102415.aspx?Export%20Crystal%20Report%20takes%20long%20time%20How%20to%20make%20it%20faster) and ...

When I am checking this using SQL Server Profiler, I find that the query is not pausing and it seems query running in screaming loop.
I really need this to export, SOS.

Answer (score 1):

If those subreports are in a repeating section (details is the worst), then there'll be one query per subreport per section in the main report.
That is, if your main report has 1000 records and the subreports are in the detail section, you'll have 4001 queries (1 for the main report, then 1000 for each subreport).
To test, remove all the subreports, then add back one by one to see if one is worse than the others.
It won't be so noticable in Crystal Reports designer as Crystal will only run the subreports when you navigate to the page. Try adding Total Page Count to the first page to see the horrible result.

Solution is typically to either do the work in a query or use SQL functions. Just depends upon your report needs.

Comment: I can not understand why crystal report doing this, it should be one query for each sub report, shouldn't be? , it works fast in viewer , but when you export it directly, its facing these kind of problems!!!! thanks to crystal team..

Comment: It works quickly in viewer because it's only running one page at a time. How could it run one query for the subreport if you're passing a parameter to the query each time it's displayed?

Comment: How can I handle this? I want it works like viewer, so what I get from your answer, its happen because I have 4 subreports in detail section. what do you mean by query or sql function. I have a factor  with main header, and products , parts , services and additions are my subreports, how this is possible to run it fast in a single page like viewer? many thanks for your time.

Comment: Your export is no slower than the viewer! If your viewer is the one from SAP, then it's not refreshing the data - that's the bit that takes the time.

Comment: Only thing you can do is to redesign the report so it doesn't have subreports in the detail section, The solution to that depends upon what your report is doing.